# Modify the layout for the Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc core:-

```
<input asp-for="b5" type="text" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Update the number to match your case.">
```

now i defined to show a tooltip on top. but on Firefox & Chrome the tool tip will be shown on random positions of the field.

second question, on all the browsers the tool tips will be shown without any layout, so how i can add a layout similar to this as mentioned on this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the recommedations from the documentation link you provided?

> Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library [Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) for positioning. You must include [popper.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js) before bootstrap.js or use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` / `bootstrap.bundle.js` which contains Popper.js in order for tooltips to work!

You also need to enable tooltips in JavaScript:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```